# Multiple trunk links on firewall

Tags: networking, cisco

I am trying to deliver VLANs (vlan 100 , vlan 200) created on a firewall
http://www.fortinet.com/sites/default/files/productdatasheets/FortiGate-800C.pdf
how ever i want to deliver them to two separate switches, i created VLANs on one of the ports but i cant create them on the second one, how can i create a second link ?

Comment: @Xander Since this question is about higher-level networking issues (i.e.: VLANs & trunking), I'd say it's *definitely* more of a [sf] topic than [su].

Comment: Just to clarify: You have two switches plugged into two separate ports on the FortiGate 800, and you want to trunk both VLANs to both switches? And what mode is the FW in (NAT/Route, I would think)?